# First simple batch file ever

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch file with a menu that with options, type in an option and it opens multiple web pages at once.  I can get it to open one web page but how do I get it to open several. So far I have:

For example, I want to hit "g" and have it open google and gmail and another website.

```
:: turn off "verbose" command writeback.
@echo off

:loop

:: write a simple list of options to console,
:main
echo Options;
echo f : facebook
echo g : google



:: Prompt for input,
set /p "strMenu=typey:"

:: Compare input through if commands,
:: `if not defined strMenu goto :menu` can be used here if prefered.
if "%strMenu%" equ "f" start "" "https://www.facebook.com"
if "%strMenu%" equ "g" start "" "http://www.google.com"


goto loop
```

Comment: Many browsers already provide the option to open multiple pages on opening. Many also provide the option to open those which were open upon last closing too. For that reason I think your idea is a relatively pointless pursuit.

Comment: Just a comment on the use of your `IF` command.  You are comparing a string and you may want to make it case insensitive. `if /I "%strMenu%"=="f"....`

Comment: What is not working? What browser are you using? Are you trying to open several at once with only one button press?

Comment: If you are using Chrome: `start "" chrome.exe http://www.google.com http://www.gmail.com http://www.facebook.com`

Comment: im basically avoiding using a mouse..because of my neuropathy, it's very hard to explain unless you've injured yourself!

Comment: Please provide a specific question title, the current one says nothing at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start "" "www.google.com"` opens google in a new tab in the default browser (when it's already open, of course - else it just opens the browser with that one tab) (at least it does for me (IE11) - different browsers may behave different here), so this should open three tabs in one browser:

```
if /i "%strMenu%" equ "f" (
  start "" "https://www.facebook.com"
  start "" "https://www.google.com"
  start "" "https://www.yahoo.com"
)
```

You should also consider the use of [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /p` (no need to press ENTER)

Comment: yes i'm using google as an example..its work related and i'm paranoid.  im trying this now!  p suggestion is great.  the less typing the better